# Net Core equivalente a User Control

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-core, usercontrol

Tengo que crear una solución en .NET Core que tendrá un proyecto MVC, con sus controladores, vistas... un proyecto para el acceso a datos con Entity Frameworky, acceso a otros datos a través de api's... Este proyecto es genérico y tiene que ser muy configurable (en función de esa configuración sabrá dónde tiene que llamar -bbdd, api's-, que información mostrar y cómo hacerlo).

Entre otras cosas la vista final llevará un selector espacial con un mapa usando un framework específico de JavaScript (Leaflet).

Esta solución (o componente) luego deberá ir incrustada en otros proyectos, que le pasarán los parámetros de configuración y en función de eso devolverá la vista que comentaba antes, que se renderizará en una parte de otra vista de ese proyecto concreto.

El tema es complicado de explicar, espero haberme hecho entender.

Antaño hubiese utizado un user control (ascx) que luego habría ido metiendo en los distintos proyectos.

Pero desde que uso MVC y ahora Core no me he encontrado con tener que hacer nada parecido así que no sé como enfocarlo. Hasta ahora era siempre dentro del mismo proyecto y usando vistas parciales o algún Custom Helper me había apañado.

He leído por ahí y he visto que se pueden usar View Compoenents o incluso TagHelpers... también de hacer un paquete Nuget con el proyecto reutilizable que descargue a cada proyecto, pero no me queda claro para que son, cómo hacerlos y si tienen las capacidades que necesito.

Quiero que sea algo centralizado, para que si hay que cambiar algo, con hacerlo en un único sitio y actualizando algo en los proyectos que lo usen (pero poca cosa, como si fuese cambiar la versión de una librería o algo parecido) se repique el cambio en todos los proyectos con poco esfuerzo de mantenimiento.

¿Me podeís echar un cable? Cualquier idea o información para entender todo esto mejor o ver cómo enfocarlo es bienvenida.

Muchas gracias.

Saludos, Héctor.

Comment: Aunque es una pregunta interesante, asi como esta redactada es totalmente basada en opiniones :(. Por favor lee [ask] y fijate de tener algo concreto. Por como esta escrita, es imposible decir que hay una respuesta correcta a la misma

Comment: Gracias por tu comentario, pero es que la pregunta es de concepto y no una duda concreta de por qué no funciona determinado código. Necesito crear un componente reutilizable en distintos proyectos con .NET Core y no sé cómo enfocarlo, por eso pregunto así de abstracto, para ver si alguien me puede encaminar a lo que quiero hacer.

Comment: Se trata de hacer algo empaquetable, que luego puedas añadir en una vista para que muestre "un control" con el que puedas interactuar y que le devuelva un valor concreto a la vista que lo contiene en función de la interactuación con el control. No sé cómo cómo enfocarlo y esa es la pregunta, soy nuevo en Core y necesito ayuda de conceptos. Gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aunque ya comenté que la pregunta era conceptual, que quizás no va mucho con la filosofía del foro, por si a alguien le puede servir, dejo lo que he visto tras investigar bastante.

Al final crearé una Librería de Clases Razor (Razor Class Library -RCL-) puesto que hasta donde he podido entender, se puede meter contenido estático como CSS, JS, imágenes... páginas razor con funcionamiento con Vista "y Back" (tienen una parte de vista y una de "controlador pegado" a ellas con los métodos OnGet, OnPost y algún otro, vamos que hay parte de vista y parte de BackEnd), puedes usar todos los servicios que quieras usar desde el back... y al final se puede referenciar en otro proyecto web, utilizando esas páginas y ese contenido estático, con lo que es altamente reutilizable en otros proyectos, de ahí la similitud a un UC antiguo (o al menos yo le veo esa similitud, puesto que tienes todo lo necesario para poder hacer un "control web" -vista, back, js, css- y es reutilizable en otros sitios puesto que es independiente).

Además creo que se puede empaquetar como un nuguet.

Con ViewComponents o TagHerlpers también se pueden hacer cosas parecidas pero para reutilizar entre proyectos es más complicado y su mentenimiento más costoso.

Saludos

Podeís ver información sobre el tema en estos enlaces:

[qué son y cómo](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/aspnet/core/razor-pages/ui-class?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio)

[Razor Pages con modelo](https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/pagemodel)

[como funciona el routing](https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/routing)

[Enlazando el modelo](https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/model-binding)

[cargarlas como parciales](https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/partial-pages)

Comment: Tras sufrir algun problema con la carga de esta arquitectura como parcial, cambié las páginas Razor por un ViewComponent dentro de la RCL y mucho mejor. para más información mirar aquí: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/es-ES/5fc7565e-b67d-4492-a52b-c7d2803d785c/pasar-parmetros-a-pagina-parcial-en-librera-de-clases-razor-rcl-net-core?forum=aspnetmvces